# Pulling scheduled meetings out of Exchange

Tags: exchange, powershell, calendar

I am inexperienced with the powershell and with Exchange Management Console. I am trying to find a way to extract all of the meeting invitations over a period of time with the following information:

- Date
- Organizer
- Requested Attendees (optional)

What would the simplest way to do this be?

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be pretty simple to do with PowerShell using some of [Glen Scales](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/)' magic. For example, [this sample](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2009/11/basic-powershell-script-to-show.html) will let you fetch appointments using EWS from PowerShell, and it should be straightforward to extend this to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Exchange Management Console / Shell type of activity. This is going to involve accessing the contents of the Information Store. You're going to have to use a protocol such as WebDAV or MAPI to pull out the data you want. Something like macros in Outlook or a script using WebDAV to access the store is your best bet, and you're probably not going to find something "off the shelf" to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this for a particular user or everyone on the system?  It might be possible using Exchange Web Services for a particular user.

Comment: For everyone. This would feed a directional graph between the people who schedule the most meetings and the ones who attend the most meetings. The metric is the amount of lost time due to the dreaded meeting.